# How do I make tinyMCE editor stay in my jQgrid textarea formedit form after first initialize?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jqgrid, tinymce

I have a jqgrid that I am trying to use tinyMCE in the text area to send/store html in my database and reload to my grid. I have a custom column with tinyMCE for the text area but after I open editform once and close it next time it is opened tinymce does not initialize and a regular textarea appears. (Also when url modal it looses focus and focuses on editform. The text is pasted to the back "Project" field instead(picture below).)What I'm I doing wrong?

Reason why my TineMCE "Links" was losing focus was because of a simple syntax error. I had modal:true in the editgrid code.

**UPDATE FOR WORKING INLINE EDIT IMPLEMENTATION**
Here are examples for correct implementation for inline edit(Thank you @Oleg): [DEMO1](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/tinyMCE2.htm) |  [DEMO2](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/tinyMCE3.htm)

**INLINE EDIT WORKING CODE SAMPLE:**

```
   { name: "note", width: 260, sortable: false, editable: true,
    //edittype: "textarea"
    edittype:'custom',
    editoptions: {
    custom_element: function (value, options) {
    var elm = $("<textarea></textarea>");
    elm.val(value);
    // give the editor time to initialize
    setTimeout(function () {

   try {
    tinymce.remove("#" + options.id);
    } catch(ex) {}
    tinymce.init({selector: "#" + options.id, plugins: "link"});
    }, 50);
    return elm;
    },
    custom_value: function (element, oper, gridval) {
    var id;
    if (element.length > 0) {
    id = element.attr("id");
    } else if (typeof element.selector === "string") {
    var sels = element.selector.split(" "),
    idSel = sels[sels.length - 1];
    if (idSel.charAt(0) === "#") {
    id = idSel.substring(1);
    } else {
    return "";
    }
    }
    if (oper === "get") {
    return tinymce.get(id).getContent({format: "row"});
    } else if (oper === "set") {
    if (tinymce.get(id)) {
    tinymce.get(id).setContent(gridval);
    }
    }
    }}
    }
```

[image: url pasted to edit project "Project" field]

jqGrid column:

```
<script src="js/jquery-1.9.0.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="js/i18n/grid.locale-en.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="js/jquery.jqGrid.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
 <script src="js/jquery-ui-1.10.3.custom.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
 <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-migrate-1.2.1.js"></script>
 <script src="tinymce/tinymce.min.js"type="text/javascript"></script>
 <script src="tinymce/jquery.tinymce.min.js"type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src= "tinymce/plugins/link/plugin.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
```

...

```
{ name:'notes',
  index:'notes',
  edittype:'custom', editable:true,
  editoptions:{
      "custom_element":function( value  , options) {
        var elm = $('<textarea></textarea>');
        elm.val( value );
        // give the editor time to initialize
        setTimeout( function() {
            tinymce.init({selector: "textarea#notes",plugins: "link"});
        }, 100);
        return elm;
      },
      "custom_value":function( element, oper, gridval) {
            if(oper === 'get') {
                return tinymce.get('notes').getContent({format: 'row'});
            } else if( oper === 'set') {
                if(tinymce.get('notes')) {
                    tinymce.get('notes').setContent( gridval );
                }
            }
      }}}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to replace the code of `custom_element` to the following

```
custom_element: function (value, options) {
    var elm = $("<textarea></textarea>");
    elm.val(value);
    // give the editor time to initialize
    setTimeout(function () {
        try {
            tinymce.remove("#" + options.id);
        } catch(ex) {}
        tinymce.init({selector: "#" + options.id, plugins: "link"});
    }, 50);
    return elm;
}
```

One more simpel

Comment: I tried this but I still get the same. On opening editform first time for rowedit it displays tinymce perfectly only that I cannot add text to modal link editor as display in pic shows, it is inserted to editform project field. But after I open second time plain textarea box displayed.

Comment: but then I open a third  time and it displays tinymce again. Strange.

Comment: @NewHistoricForm: Look at [the demo](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/tinyMCE.htm) which uses the code which I posted. Can you reproduce the problems here?

Comment: Your example does the same thing. When you first open to editrow it display fine. But once you close and reopen row editor is gone. But your links modal works fine, trying to figure out why mine does not.

Comment: @NewHistoricForm: Which web browser you use for your tests? In IE10  and Chrome 37 I can open edit form multiple time and see always tinyMCE editor.

Comment: Firefox 32.0.1 Does that make a diference? Ill check on chrome.

Comment: Strange, on chrome it always display but cannot insert text in url modal. In safari the same behavior as firefox.

Comment: @NewHistoricForm: What you can't insert exactly in the demo? I have no problems to "Insert Link" in Chrome and IE. I could reproduce now problems in Firefox.

Comment: in your demo tinyMCE textarea loads first time other time not then loads again and so forth in firefox and safari. Chrome seems to be ok.

Comment: @NewHistoricForm: I'm not expert in tinyMCE, but it seems that tinyMCE have exception sometimes in Firefox. One should probably debug non-minimized code of tinyMCE to find the place of exception and probably suggest the corresponding workaround. It seems some kind of timing problem. One can insert additional `setTimeout` in case of removing

Comment: setTimeout? how so? And what about the url modal? It seems everytime I try to type it focuses on the edit form "name" field instead.Your demo is fine and does not have this problem

Comment: @NewHistoricForm: It seems I found the reason. One need enclose `tinymce.remove("#" + options.id);` in `try { ... } catch(ex) {}` block. I updated [the demo](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/tinyMCE.htm) and the text of my answer.

Comment: That did it. Shows every rowedit in all browsers!Thanks. Now the only problem is the url modal window. It opens but when I try to type it looses focus and focuses on editform instead. Your demo does not do that.Any idea what could be causing it?

Comment: On keydown it looses focus but when I right click and paste with mouse it is ok.

Comment: nevermind. For some reason I had `modal:true` in my editGridRow doubleclick function. Deleted it and it's all good. Thanks Oleg

Comment: One more question: How to convert the `"` to `quot` in links posted like `<a title="tr" href="http://www.amada-stage.com/webmaster/edit-projects.html" target="_blank">eee</a>` using jqgrid. I prefer to avoid doing it server side.

Comment: @NewHistoricForm: You can use [serializeEditData](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:form_editing#events) callback to have full control about the data posted to the server during form editing.

Comment: @NewHistoricForm: Sorry, but I don't know and don't use tinyMCE myself.

Comment: Understood , what about removing editability of columns in inline edit but leaving them in form edit?

Comment: @NewHistoricForm: Sorry, but I don't understand scenario which you do. Why you make the column `notes` *unconditionally* non-editable for inline editing? Why you need to use *both* inline editing and form editing? Moreover you starts one editing in `ondblClickRow` and another in `onSelectRow`. It's known that different web browser have different processing of click and double-click (the order can be different). One line can't be edited **at the same time** in both inline and form editing. So I can't follow your goals.

Comment: simply I want only the checkmark to be editable on rowselect and the rest editable in editform with double click. Your saying that's not possible?

Comment: @NewHistoricForm: I don't understand what you mean. The current code try to start form editing (`editGridRow`) inside of do `ondblClickRow`. Typically in the same moment (just a moment before) will be the same row selected, `onSelectRow` will be called and you start explicitly inline editing (`editRow`). It can't work!

Comment: @NewHistoricForm: I can't follow you. What you mean under "checkmark Column editable". I don't see any advantage of usage both inline editing and form editing in one grid. If it do required then you can use `navGrid` to start form editing of selected row and use `ondblClickRow` to start inline editing. All above have still no relation to your question about tinyMCE.

Comment: It's connected because I want certain columns, including one with tinymce,to be uneditable or non accesable on inline edit. But column with tinymce does not post key:value to server at all even if I leave it editable during inline edit.

Comment: @NewHistoricForm: Sorry, but you should choose *one* scenario and ask the corresponding question. Do you want to implement inline editing with tinyMCE or you don't want it? Is your problem is that you have problem with making column non-editable? Do you make another choice and you want do use tinyMCE in inline editing and your problem with getting results of editing? Do you tried to prepare the corresponding demo?

Comment: @NewHistoricForm: I made [the demo](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/tinyMCE2.htm) which send results of inline editing to dummy url. I can see in HTTP traffic that inline editing do send the result of tinyMCE to the dummy url. [The demo](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/tinyMCE3.htm) uses "clientArray" as URL and one can see that one do can save the data in the grid after inline editing. So I don't see any global problems with the tinyMCE in jqGrid. the only small issue is including of `<p>` and `</p>` in editing data, but it's not real problem.

Comment: Thanks for the greetings. I updated my question with examples for inline edit implementation, i got it working. Problem/Question: When I try to use `serializeRowData` from inline edit it does not fire.I send certain columns thru encode script and return encoded postdata. I already use `serializeEditData` for editform for this and works great.I tried to implement same code for `serializeRowData` but deos not encode posdata. I'll will open new question for this problem if needed. Thanks

Comment: @NewHistoricForm: You are welcome! You should post the code fragment which not work. It helps to help you. I suppose that you used `serializeRowData` in a wrong way. In [the documentation](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:inline_editing#saverow) you can read that `serializeRowData` is "grid options" (not an option of `editRow` for example) so you should define it on the same place as jqGrid callbacks `onSelectRow`, `loadComplete`, `serializeGridData` and other. I guess that you used `serializeRowData` in a wrong place.

Comment: Could you please help with this please [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28513204/jqgrid-how-to-send-info-from-tinymce-column-while-edit-is-disabled-in-in-line-ed](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28513204/jqgrid-how-to-send-info-from-tinymce-column-while-edit-is-disabled-in-in-line-ed)

Comment: I know your busy but please if I set this column to `Editable: False` why does it send data posted as `""` empty? And how to fix that so it sends data from column when set to `editable: false`?

Comment: @NewHistoricForm: Sorry,  but I don't use tinyMCE myself. JavaScript language is **case sensitive**. `Editable` and `editable` are absolutely different names. `False` is unknown variable and `false` is well-known Boolean constant. You need always hold the case of identifier names.

Comment: Sorry for typo with cap E it was a mistake.  But i think this has to do with custom_element. Could you please give me any advice on this [link]( http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28513204/jqgrid-how-to-send-info-from-tinymce-column-while-edit-is-disabled-in-in-line-ed )