# Jqgrid and jqxeditor integration

Tags: jqgrid

I'm trying to integrate jqx editor with jqgrid. It works fine for the row edit part (get operator), but I'm still having problems for the add part (set operator). The dialog window appears with the editor, but I don't know how to get the data from the jqxeditor.
How should I implement my custom_value function in this case (text field)?
Thanks!

```
$Notegrid.jqGrid({
        url: al.rooturl + suffix,
        datatype: "json",
        mtype: "POST",
        loadonce: false,
        altRows: false,
        colNames: ["ID", "Note","Liée à","Actions"],
        colModel: [
            { name: "id", index: "id", width: 80, align: "center",sorttype: "int" },
            { name: "text", index: "text",editable: true, edittype:"custom", editoptions:{
                    custom_element:function( value, options) {
                        elm = $('<div id="'+options.id+'"></div>');                         
                        // give the editor time to initialize
                        setTimeout( function() {
                            elm.jqxEditor({ 
                                tools: 'bold italic underline size', 
                                width: '100%', 
                                height: '100%'
                            });
                            elm.val( value );
                            }, 100
                        );

                        return elm;
                    },
                    custom_value:function( element, oper, gridval) {    
                        if(oper === 'set'){
                            // how to set the data ?
                        }else{
                            if(oper === 'get') {
                                return element.jqxEditor('val');
                            }
                    }

                    }}, width: 500, formatter: formatText },...
```

Comment: Could you provide the demo (for example JSFiddle demo) which can be used to reproduce the problem? The demo should use non-minimized version of jqGrid: `jquery.jqgrid.src.js` instead of `jquery.jqgrid.min.js`. If one can debug the code then one could easy find the answer on your question.

Comment: By the way the demos: [this one](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/tinyMCE2.htm) and [this one](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/tinyMCE3.htm) which I created for [the answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/25870585/315935) (see many comments to the answer) demonstrates the usage of [tinymce](http://www.tinymce.com/) editor which have very close functionality to jqxEditor.

Comment: Thanks! I already tried with tinymce and the same code you provided in your previous answer but sometimes I have conflicts with another tinymce instances which are loaded on the same page (in another tabs). The one in jqgrid works fine but the others are not launched with this error:
TypeError: p is not a constructor
/TinyMCE/tinymce/jscripts/tiny_mce/tiny_mce.js
Ligne : 1

Comment: Here the fiddle example: http://jsfiddle.net/nfo2aaj1/17/

Answer (score 1):

I don't know `jqxEditor`, but debugging of your demo shows that editing works, but saved text contains double text. To fix the problem you can try to use

```js
return element.jqxEditor('val')[0];
```

instead of

```js
return element.jqxEditor('val');
```

See http://jsfiddle.net/OlegKi/nfo2aaj1/18/

**UPDATED:** I understand now better your problem. First of all you tried to use form editing of local data which is not supported out of the box in jqGrid 4.6. It's implemented in jqGrid starting with 4.7 version. The next problem is the usage of `div` created in `custom_element` for `jqxEditor`. The problem is the following. One have to create an DOM element and return it (or jQuery wrapper on it like you do) from `custom_element` callback. jqGrid assign then `id` and `name` to the element. So assigning `id` in your implementation of `custom_element` callback is not required. The problem, which one have in form editing, is `jqxEditor` seems to overwrite the attributes. As the workaround I suggest to create additional **outer** `<div>` together with the main `<div>` forwarded to `jqxEditor`. The corresponding code will be

```js
custom_element: function (value, options) {
    var elm = $("<div><div></div></div>");                          
    // give the editor time to initialize
    setTimeout(function() {
        elm.children("div").jqxEditor({ 
            tools: 'bold italic underline size', 
            width: '100%', 
            height: '100px'
        });
        elm.children("div").val(value);
    }, 100);

    return elm;
},
custom_value: function (element, oper, gridval) {   
    if (oper === 'set') {
        // how to set the data ?
    } else {
        if (oper === 'get') {
            return element.children("div").jqxEditor('val');
        }
    }
}
```

The corresponding demo http://jsfiddle.net/OlegKi/nfo2aaj1/23/ seems to work. I used the latest version (4.9.2) of free jqGrid in the demo. It support form editing of local data. The demo sees both inline and form editing and both seems to work without any problem.

Comment: Thank you for this fix! My main problem is about the "set" part in the custom_value function. When you click on the "+" button to add a new row and you submit, the data are not collected. Any idea ?

Comment: @Bibou: You are welcome! The reason of the problem with "Add" button: you use *form editing* for Add button which don't support editing of **local** data in jqGrid 4.6. You can use `add: false` in `navGrid` and then call `inlineNav` to add Add button used using inline editing. It should work.

Comment: @Bibou: See **UPDATED** part of my answer for additional information and for working demo.